# How to compare two arrays from the database and get the difference

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having trouble with arrays in php; specifically, I want to compare two arrays in the database and get their difference. And the difference will be stored in the database. I'm new in php.

My codes looks like:

This is where I get my arrays:

```
$year = $_POST['year'];
$course = $_POST['Course'];
$block = $_POST['block'];

$cheetah = mysql_query("SELECT stud_valid_nos FROM exam_students WHERE stud_subject_id = '$subject_id'")or die(mysql_error());  
while($validnos = mysql_fetch_array($cheetah)){
    $nos = $validnos['stud_valid_nos'];
    }
$tiger = mysql_query("SELECT sec_id_num FROM exam_sections WHERE sec_year = '$year' AND sec_course = '$course' AND sec_block = '$block'")or die(mysql_error()); 
while($idnum = mysql_fetch_array($tiger)){
    $id = $idnum['stud_valid_nos'];
    }

if($nos ???? $id){ ///this is where the arrays being compared.

inserts only the difference

}

else{

inserts the full array in the database
}
```

### Update

I've decided not to use array any more, maybe some of you has a point, so I've reorganized my codes but it's still not working. How can I add student numbers in my database with no duplicates?

Here is my new code:

```
$cheetah = mysql_query("SELECT stud_valid_nos FROM exam_students WHERE stud_subject_id = '$subject_id'")or die(mysql_error());  
if(mysql_num_rows($cheetah)>0){

while($validnos = mysql_fetch_array($cheetah)){
    $nos = $validnos['stud_valid_nos'];

    $tiger = mysql_query("SELECT sec_id_num,sec_email FROM exam_sections WHERE sec_id_num <> '$nos' AND sec_year = '$year' AND sec_course = '$course' AND sec_block = '$block'")or die(mysql_error());
while($idnum = mysql_fetch_assoc($tiger)){
    $id = $idnum['sec_id_num'];
    $email = $idnum['sec_email'];


    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam_students (stud_valid_nos, stud_email, stud_subject_id, stud_group_id ) VALUES ('$id','$email','$subject_id','$examinergroupid')")or die(mysql_error());
    $last = mysql_insert_id();
    $password = genRandomString();
    $rawr = mysql_query("INSERT INTO exam_passwords (pass_user_id,pass_password,pass_subject_id,pass_exam_id) VALUES ('$last','$password', '$subject_id', 0)")or die(mysql_error());

    }

    }
```

Maybe I should use the NOT IN or IS NULL functions in mysql_query? How can I get rid of my problem?

Comment: You can probably do this all in the database - I can't work out what you're trying to achieve, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Your result data will not be arrays since you're reassigning them each time in cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$diff = array_diff($nos, $id);
if (count($diff)) {
     // insert diff
} else {
     // insert full array
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

Be careful - think about what you really want to get:

Look at this example:

```
$arr1 = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
$arr2 = array("c", "d", "e", "f");

$diff1 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$diff2 = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

$diff1 contains "a" and "b" because it will return what is in the $arr1 and not in $arr2

$diff2 contains "e" and "f" because it will return what is in the $arr2 and not in $arr1

If you want to get full diff you have to merge $diff1 and $diff2 together:

```
$f_diff = array_merge($diff1, $diff2);
```

Then:

```
if (count($f_diff)) {
    //insert difference
}
else {
    //insert all
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine both conditions like this ?:

```
INSERT INTO exam_sections
VALUES (SELECT * 
        FROM exam_sections
        WHERE sec_year = '$year' AND sec_course = '$course' AND sec_block = '$block'
        AND  stud_subject_id != '$subject_id'
        )
```

Columns and Values for the INSERT need to be arranged properly !